# Combine filters in mongodb

Tags: .net, mongodb, .net-core

```
public class Page
{
    public string Title {get;set;}
    public bool IsHomePage {get;set;}
}
```

In the repository, I'm using Sample in order to retrieve documents

```
return await db.myCollection
               .Aggregate()
               .Match(filter)
               .ToListAsync();
```

> is it possible to expand this query in order to return all documents that
> has property `IsHomePage` set to `true` and the rest
> to be with `IsHomePage` set to `false`;

```
var filter = Builders<Post>.Filter.Eq(x => x.IsHomePage, true);
var homePageDocsFilter = await db.myCollection
                   .Aggregate()
                   .Match(filter)
                   .ToListAsync();  // can this be in-memory call?

var filter2 = Builders<Post>.Filter.Eq(x => x.IsHomePage, false);
var otherDocs = await db.myCollection
                   .Aggregate()
                   .Match(filter2)
                   .ToListAsync(); // can this be in-memory call?
```

**how to combine this two above filters?**

```
return await db.myCollection
                   .Aggregate()
                   .Match(COMBINED_FILTER)
                   .ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

> how to combine this two above filters?

Typed options:

```
  var filter = Builders<Post>.Filter.Eq(x => x.IsHomePage, true) | Builders<Post>.Filter.Eq(x => x.IsHomePage, false);


  var filter = Builders<Post>.Filter.Or(Builders<Post>.Filter.Eq(x => x.IsHomePage, false), Builders<Post>.Filter.Eq(x => x.IsHomePage, true))
```

add `Sort` stage if you need particular ordering